# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 from randomly switching projects to run in IIS Express when they're configured to run in Local IIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Our team recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017.  We store our server settings in the project file to use Local IIS, but opening up the properties of the project shows it to be using IIS Express.  This occurs seemingly at random and has been affecting random teammates ever since we upgraded.

[image: IIS Express]

The .csproj file in source control shows the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
  <IISExpressSSLPort />
  <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
  <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
  <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
  <Use64BitIISExpress />
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

as well as:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <FlavorProperties GUID="{...}">
      <WebProjectProperties>
        <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
        <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
        <DevelopmentServerPort>53703</DevelopmentServerPort>
        <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
        <IISUrl>http://localhost/MyProject</IISUrl>
        <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
        <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
        <CustomServerUrl>
        </CustomServerUrl>
        <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
      </WebProjectProperties>
    </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

When this occurs, it seems to randomly set `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` to `False` and teammates are accidentally checking in this change when they don't catch it.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told by Microsoft support that this is a known issue with Visual Studio 15.6:

> Bill Hiebert [MSFT] · Mar 21 at 10:11 PM 1
>
> Apologies for the delayed response, but we have identified the issue
>   and are working on a fix. The problem manifests itself if the
>   `<FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">`
>   section is missing from the .user file which can happen more easily in
>   15.6.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/208768/vs-156-does-not-respect-the-apply-server-settings.html

Turns out some team members haven't patched up their Visual Studio to latest yet.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `.csproj.user` of the project and disable IIS Express:

```xml
<UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
```

Comment: `UseIISExpress` was already set to false as shown in the 2nd code block of the original question.

Comment: It is the `.csproj.user` file. It is a different file.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Missed that distinction.  Either way, it wasn't an issue with the .user file either since the setting kept getting overridden to true, seemingly every other time they opened the project.  It was a bug with Visual Studio itself and it was patched by Microsoft already.

Comment: @Kcoder I'm running 15.8.1 and it still seems to be a problem, is there a workaround?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Are you working with a team?  The problem for me was that members of my team didn't update and they were checking in updated .csproj files that unintentionally turned IIS Express on.  I was using the latest, but they were still using 15.6.

Comment: @Kcoder I work with a team, but that isn't relevant right now. I'm converting a website developed with VS 2013 .NET 4.5.1 to VS 2017 .NET 4.6.1 because those are the minimum requirements for the message broker we are testing. The question I asked you doesn't seem to be valid anymore because visual studio added the necessary GUID to the web.config file. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, this was exactly my issue.